# Java I/O File Not Found

Tags: java, file, io, filenotfoundexception

Currently trying to write a program to take input from a file and store it in an array. However, whenever I try to run the program the file cannot be found (despite file.exists() and file.canRead() returning true).

Here is my code:

```
    public void getData (String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    File file = new File (fileName);
    System.out.println(file.exists());
    System.out.println(file.canRead());
    System.out.println(file.getPath());
    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner (new FileReader (file));
    int entryCount = 0;     // Store number of entries in file

    // Count number of entries in file
    while (fileScanner.nextLine() != null)
    {
        entryCount++;
    }

    dirArray = new Entry[entryCount];   //Create array large enough for entries
    System.out.println(entryCount);

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ArrayDirectory testDirectory = new ArrayDirectory();


    try
    {
        testDirectory.getData("c://example.txt");
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

(In it's current state the method is only designed to count the number of lines and create the array)

The console output is as follows: true true c:/example.txt

The program seems to throw a 'FileNotFoundException' on the line where the scanner is instantiated.

One thing I have noticed when checking the 'file' object when debugging is although it's 'path' variable has the value "c:\example.txt", it's 'filePath' value is null. Not sure if this is relevant to the issue or not

EDIT: After Brendan Long's answer I have updated the 'catch' block. The stack trace reads as follows:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
    at assignment2.ArrayDirectory.getData(ArrayDirectory.java:138)
    at assignment2.ArrayDirectory.main(ArrayDirectory.java:193)
```

Seemingly the scanner doesn't recognize the file and thus can't find the line

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java new File() says FileNotFoundException but file exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307622/java-new-file-says-filenotfoundexception-but-file-exists)

Comment: @BrendanLong I visited that page before posting this and no solution worked, hence this question

Comment: Why do you have two slashes in the path name?

Comment: @ajb That's just how I've been taught to do it. Either way it still recognises the address as file.getPath() returns "c:\example.txt"

Comment: @AJCol I think somebody was confused.  In Java, you have to double a backslash (\\) to use it in a string literal, but you don't need to do that with a regular slash (`/`).  The Windows file system will see this as two slashes, which may or may not be harmless--I'm not sure.

Comment: Like I said, using '/', '//' or '\\' doesn't change anything and is still interpreted as "c:/example.txt" so it's irrelevant

Answer (score 3):

This code probably doesn't do what you want:

```
try
{
    testDirectory.getData("c://example.txt");
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    new FileNotFoundException("File not found");
}
```

If you catch any exception, you run the constructor for a FileNotFoundException and then throw it away. Try doing this:

```
try
{
    testDirectory.getData("c://example.txt");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, updated the question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

According to [the javadoc for Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29), `nextLine()` throws this exception when there is no more input.  Your program seems to expect it to return `null`, but that's now how it works (unlike, say, `BufferedReader` which *does* return `null` at the end of the input).  Use [`hasNextLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine%28%29) to make sure there's another line before using `nextLine`.

Comment: hasNextLine() returns true although I was expecting it to return false which is strange...

Comment: @AJCol You did use `hasNextLine` in the loop, right?  Instead of just once?  I'd expect `hasNextLine()` to return `true` the first N times and then return `false`, if your file has N lines in it.

Comment: I have just printed out .next() which actually prints the first word in the file so I guess it doesn't have anything to do with the file. Thankyou for steering me in the right direction!