# how to use printwriter to create and write to a file

Tags: java, file, filenotfoundexception, printwriter

I am trying to create a new file and print data to said file using the printwriter class.

My code looks like this

```
File Fileright = new File("C:\\GamesnewOrder.txt"); 

PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(Fileright);

for(int i =0;i<=Games2.length-1;i++)
{
    pw.println(Games2[i]);

}

pw.close();
```

I do have the main method with a `throwsIOException`.

The error `java.iofilenotfound` exception keeps appearing at the line where I am creating the printwriter. So is the printwriter not creating the file?

Comment: Explain what you mean by error. Do you mean a compile time error or is an `Exception` thrown at run time?

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
C:\GamesnewOrder.txt(Access is denied)(in java.io.FileOutputStream)

Comment: Put that in your question, please.

Comment: You might not be able to write directly in the C:\ folder. Try writing to your documents folder or something like that (I don't have windows so I can't try it myself).

Comment: Here is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19309163/1031312. In future please do a little search before making a duplicate question.

Comment: Thank you nmore....that was the solution, I wish I knew that an hour ago.

Answer (score 3):

the code works for me.

```
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;

  public class NewClass {

     void n() throws FileNotFoundException {
             File Fileright = new File("/home/ubuntu/Documents/f.txt");

             PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(Fileright);

             for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
                pw.println(i);
                System.out.println(i);

             }

             pw.close();
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

             new NewClass().n();
      }

}
```

output:(in file: /home/ubuntu/Documents/f.txt)

0
1
2
3

Answer (score 2):

> FileNotFoundException - If the given file object does not denote an
>   existing, writable regular file and a new regular file of that name
>   cannot be created, or if some other error occurs while opening or
>   creating the file

Please check the file Permission, you may use `canRead()` , `canWrite()`  to check that, but it may not be sufficient enough.