# "cannot find the file specified", checked multiple times & looks correct

Tags: java, audio, embedded-resource, clip

How come my file isn't being read correctly? I checked, and the res folder is a resource in this project.

```
public class Testing {

    private File file;
    private Clip clip;
    private AudioInputStream audioIn;

    public Testing() {
        String path = "/res/shot.mp3";
        file = new File(path);
        System.out.println(file.toString());
        try {
            audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioIn);
            clip.start();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // java.io.FileNotFoundException: \res\shot.mp3 
        // (The system cannot find the path specified)
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Testing();
    }
}
```

My Package Explorer.

[image]

I tried changing the path to `/SoundTest/res/shot.mp3`, still no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java new File() says FileNotFoundException but file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307622/java-new-file-says-filenotfoundexception-but-file-exists)

Comment: No luck. I get the same error, except the path is now obviously shot.mp3 in the console.

Comment: `/res/shot.mp3` is an absolute path. This will only work if `res` is in the root directory of your file system. You say "The resource folder is a folder in this project". Where is the project located?

Comment: Is this file must be a real file or will package in the jar ?

Comment: @WilliamBurnham The project is in one of my eclipse workspace folders, then in that folder, is the bin, src, etc., as well as my res folder.

Comment: @MichaelKellam change folder name from `res` to `resources` and use path as `shot.mp3` only.

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Answer (score 1):

`/res/shot.mp3` is an absolute path. This will only work if `res` is in the root directory of your file system. You say "The resource folder is a folder in this project". From your screenshot, the directory structure is something like

```
/home/your_user_dir/your_project_dir
                                    /src ...
                                    /bin
                                    /res
```

So you need to change the creation of your `File` object such that either it has the correct relative path, or uses an absolute path.

You can use

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/res/shot.mp3");
```

and then create your `AudioInputStream` with `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(InputStream)` -- [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html)

So change your code to

```
    String path = "/res/shot.mp3";
    InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);
    try {
        audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(is);
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioIn);
        clip.start();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: *"This will give you a url that you can convert to a file object,"* Not a) if it's coming from the web or b) **inside a Jar.**. An URL can cover many more sources of data than a file can, so once the code gains a valid URL, either get an input stream directly from it or (safer with Java Sound, which often requires a buffered input stream) use the URL directly.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks for your comment, I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the file beeing present, are you sure you want to use a `.mp3`-file? `AudioSystem.getAudioFileTypes()` returns `WAVE`, `AU` and `AIFF` as supported types on my machine.

Furthermore is the exception you are presenting in your question matching the source code you shared? In your code its `shot.mp3`, but the exception refers to a `.wav` file.

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry. I tried using both .mp3 and .wav files, forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot use

```
file = new File(path);
audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
```

If you want to get the file in the resources folder you have to get using the Method `getResource()`

Change this in your code :

```
    URL url = Testing.class.getResource("/res/shot.mp3");
    AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(audioIn);//surround with try catch block i didn't use here
```

hope this may helpful