# Keep encountering FileNotFoundException (eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse

I am attempting to take input from a file called gift1.in, however I keep getting a file not found error. Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: where is this `gift1.in` file located? is it on the project root? `FileNotFoundException` can be caused by several cases. Please take a look on [previous QA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19309163/4648586).

Comment: Yep, located in USACO folder (project root)

Comment: check on your project folder, is there folder named `target` (or any folder that contains the compiled `jar` file), copy the `gift1.in` into that folder and try to run again. i think it just path issue.

Comment: Ah, the only folders in the project root appear to be bin and src. I put the gift1.in in this directory. Darn, I can't figure this out :(

Comment: Try calling `f.getAbsolutePath()` right after you instantiate it so that you have a better idea of where it thinks it is. Then check your Run Configuration for what its working directory is.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with where your file is. (At least not necessarily) Eclipse requires you to handle the `fileNotFoundException`, and will not compile unless you have a `throws` deceleration or surround it in a try catch. It has nothing to do with the file itself, just the fact that you are doing io operations and eclipse requires you to handle some of the errors

Comment: @GBlodgett Ah, Java is cheeky that way... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in the screenshot is a unhandled exception *compiler* error.

`FileNotFoundException` is a checked exception since it derives from `IOException`.

A checked exception will always generate a compiler error when compiled if not caught or thrown.

Either add `throws FileNotFoundException` in `main` or put the code throwing it in a `try/catch` block.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException
```

or

```
Scanner input = null;
try {
  input = new Scanner(f);
}
catch {
  System.Out.Print("File not found");
  return 1;
}
```

The file also needs to be in a resource folder for the build script to copy to the target folder to run.

I am not sure about Eclipse, but the standard I have seen is for the resource folder to be located  in `src/main/resources`.

Comment: Yes, but why would the file not be found? I put it in the project root. Excuse me if I'm misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have eclipse right now but the problem might be the path. Try this

```
File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "gift1.in");
```

or

```
File f = new File("[/absolute/path/to/file]");
```